# google calendar in outlook - unable to add reminders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar, reminder

I've subscribed to my Google calendar inside Outlook via the secret-ical url for 2-way syncing. However, I'm unable to add reminders to my events as I'm prompted with an error message saying:

> The reminder for 'xxxx' will not appear because the item is in a folder that doesn't support reminders.

All the suggestions I could find don't work

- setting the option "Show reminders"
- re-connecting the calendar
- running the 'outlook.exe /cleanreminders' command

Does Google calendar with reminders work for you guys? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research on the error, I found that when the reminder is set in a separate pst file, and the below option is not selected, the issue may occur. If it's your issue, it’s suggested that you could try the following steps and check if there're any differences.

[image]

Comment: no unfortunately that's the option i've already tried

Comment: Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode (win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.